# Data parameter is not passed to SOQL query when there are passed from an APEX test class.method()

Tags: apex, soql, sobject, failing-tests

I've created a class and an APEX method which uses a SOQL query to retrieve a single data item which I then process.
This query takes a Salesforce ID as a parameter (in string format/type), and returns a string.

This works fine when I call the method directly, but doesn't work when the method is called from a test class method.

Here's my class:

```
public class EllisphereToRC {
    public static String giveTheMonthOfTheFiscalYear(String accountId) {
        String ReturnValue ='';

        List<ELLISPHERE__Elli_FinancialOrigin__c> theRecord = new List<ELLISPHERE__Elli_FinancialOrigin__c>();
        theRecord = [SELECT Name FROM ELLISPHERE__Elli_FinancialOrigin__c WHERE ELLISPHERE__Elli_KeyFigures_Account__c = :accountId LIMIT 1];

        if (theRecord.size() > 0) {
            String FirstMonthFiscalYear = '';
            String MonthToEvaluate = ''; 
            try {
                FirstMonthFiscalYear = theRecord[0].Name.subString(0, 5);
                MonthToEvaluate = FirstMonthFiscalYear.right(2);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}

            switch on MonthToEvaluate {
                when '01' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Février'); 
                    ReturnValue = 'Février';
                }
                when '02' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Mars'); 
                    ReturnValue = 'Mars';
                }
                when '03' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Avril');
                    ReturnValue = 'Avril';
                }
                when '04' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Mai');
                    ReturnValue = 'Mai';
                }
                when '05' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Juin');
                    ReturnValue = 'Juin';
                }
                when '06' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Julliet');
                    ReturnValue = 'Julliet';
                }
                when '07' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Août');
                    ReturnValue = 'Août';
                }
                when '08' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Septembre');
                    ReturnValue = 'Septembre';
                }
                when '09' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Octobre');
                    ReturnValue = 'Octobre';
                }
                when '10' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Novembre');
                    ReturnValue = 'Novembre';
                }
                when '11' {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Décembre');
                    ReturnValue = 'Décembre';
                }
                when '12'  {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Janvier');
                    ReturnValue = 'Janvier';
                }
                when null {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Null');
                    ReturnValue = null;
                }
                when else {
                    System.debug('MonthToEvaluate => Other');
                    ReturnValue = 'Other';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            ReturnValue = 'No record found with given Account ID and Key Figures Account.';
        }
        return ReturnValue;
    }
    public void dummy(){}
}
```

Here's my test class:

```
@IsTest 
private class TestEllisphereToRC {

    @TestSetup 
    static void setup(){}

    @IsTest 
    static void testGiveTheMonthOfTheFiscalYear(){
        String accountId1 = '0010900001rolCxAAI'; // Id of a valid account in table ELLISPHERE__Elli_FinancialOrigin__c
        String result = '';

        result = EllisphereToRC.giveTheMonthOfTheFiscalYear('0010900001rolCxAAI'); // Call to the method to be tested with a valid account
        System.assertEquals('Janvier',result,'La méthode giveTheMonthOfTheFiscalYear doit renvoyer le bon mois pour cet id de compte');

        String accountId2 = '123456789'; // Id of a non-existent account in table ELLISPHERE__Elli_FinancialOrigin__c
        try{
            result = EllisphereToRC.giveTheMonthOfTheFiscalYear(accountId2); // Call to the method with an invalid account
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.assertEquals('No record found with given Account ID and Key Figures Account.',e.getMessage(),'La méthode doit renvoyer le message d'erreur correct pour cet id de compte');
        }
    }
}
```

I've found that when I call my method manually, by passing it an Account ID.
The account ID is passed as an argument to the SOQL query.

When I use the test method, the account ID doesn't seem to be passed as an argument to the SOQL query.

**Question:** Has anyone already experienced this kind of problem?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Hard-coding ids is a red flag, especially in tests. Test methods, by default, cannot access the "real" data of your org (aside from "setup objects" like User, Group, RecordType, and a handful of others). You should be explicitly creating test data as part of your unit tests (it gets cleaned up after the test run has finished).

Comment: All data, and test are done in dev, not in production. I made a set of tests to conduct these tests.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If you run your test in dev org, it cannot access the data in your dev org. The correct solution to this problem is to explicitly create test data inside of your test class. That isn't the _only_ approach, but it is the _correct_ approach. You can, for example, also create a series of .csv files, upload them as static resources, then use `Test.loadData()`.

Comment: Ok, perfect, I've modified the method according to your comment.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Just somewhere inside of the test class. The "best practice" is to create test data inside of an `@TestSetup` annotated method, but it could be done inside of individual `@isTest` methods or in a static method that you'd call at the start of each of your test methods.

Comment: Pro tip: replace your switch statement with a `Map <String,String> monthNamesByMonthNumber` and your code gets shorter and is easier to test - otherwise your testmethod, to get coverage, needs to have test data for every month